# Get ActiveRecord from Redis Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, redis

In my application, I have many standard SQL queries, like find model by id.

I want to cache these queries in Redis (for 1 hour as example).

I can store a JSON representation of the model, fetch and parse this string, but it will be a ruby Hash.

This isn't convenient because I need to manipulate these objects like an ActiveRecord object.

How I can transform this object from a hash to AR?

Can `Marshal.dump` help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` to serialize AR objects and then load them back. This has some drawbacks though. With the current version of rails the autoloading does not play nice with `Marshal.load`. There was a recent PR to get `Marshal.load` and the autoloader working together. (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8246).